# Access level related question

Tags: permissions

I got curious if there exist a access level to the system with is above the **root** user?

Comparable, in Windows above the **Administrator** are: **SYSTEM** and **TrustedInstaller** with is *probably* the highest access level

Comment: Welcome, no there isn't, `root` is the all powerful superuser.

Comment: I would doubt it because by attempt to modiffy some system files I get the "Access Denied" error, so it's limited

Comment: What exactly do you do to get that error? It's no a good practice to use the `root` user to mess with the system, if that's what you are doing.

Comment: @MichalD. if the "system" is a container then the "root" might be a "fakeroot" only for the container.  "Access Denied" can show up if there's certain locks on the file or attributes set though, but that's a different set of issues.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I wanted to harden some the system by changing the values of some config-related files

Comment: @MichalD. *which* files?  Some are controlled by other processes and SystemD will place a systemwide hold on them to prevent breakage, but we need to know what files you were 'adjusting' that you couldn't edit.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like):

> In Unix-like computer OSes (such as Linux), root is the conventional
> name of the user who has all rights or permissions (to all files and
> programs) in all modes (single- or multi-user).

And the use of the account:

> It is often recommended that no-one use root as their normal user
> account, since simple typographical errors in entering commands
> can cause major damage to the system. Instead, a normal user account
> should be used, and then either the su (substitute user) or sudo
> (substitute user do) command is used.

Comment: I know that and use root **only** when I must

Comment: @MichalD. Ok, but it's a good advice to anyone that reads the answer.